# AngularJS Converting date wrong

Tags: java, angularjs

I have the following opening tag in my template:

```
<div class="t-th" title="{{row.created | date:'h:MMa'}}">
```

When `row.created` is `1436908657492` (7/14/15 5:17PM) the compiled tag is:

```
<div class="t-th ng-binding" title="5:07PM" ng-style="_stResize(5)" style="flex: 1 1 0px;">
```

The ngStyle/style attributes are added by a directive elsewhere; my problem is that 5:07 is not the correct conversion for the timestamp, 5:17  is. Why would Angular get the conversion 10 minutes off?

Comment: wow...is this that hard to look up in the docs? RTFM

Comment: do you respond that way to every question? Confusing a lowercase and a capital after 8 hours of work isn't all that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<div class="t-th" title="{{row.created | date:'h:MMa'}}">
```

to this:

```
<div class="t-th" title="{{row.created | date:'h:mma'}}">
```

"MM" stands for month in a year padded 01-12 (July is 7th month in a year, so Angular does it job correctly).
"mm" stands for minutes in hour padded 00-59.

[Angular docs for date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Answer (score 0):

Try `date:'h:mma'` instead. `MM` is month.